# Dry Run Capability: How to do a function that prints either the commands OR executes them

Tags: zsh

*Any alternative suggestions about how to add in a dry-run capability would be appreciated.*

I am trying to create a function that runs in 'dry-run' mode or live mode.

for example (pseudo-code):

```
function do-stuff() {
   dry_run_or_real 
   brew install java
   for x in dir ; do echo $x ; done
}

function dry_run_or_real() {
   if [ ! -z "$GLOBAL_DRY_RUN" ] ; then 
      echo "We would do this:$*"
   else 
      # we are actually running the code
      $* 
   fi
}
```

If GLOBAL_DRY_RUN is set is this text:

```
We would do this:
brew install java
for x in dir ; do echo $x ; done
```

BUT the above commands would not be executed.

The large constraint is that do-stuff's body must have only minimal changes to it to support the dry-run testing code:

1. we will have many, many do-stuff functions
2. functions will be added to and edited by inexperienced devs so anything complex will probably get broken.

Comment: It's not really clear what your goal is. Your example would just require the writer of the function to supply a test. In addition the way your're nesting it would make it harder to control. Your `do-stuff` would need something like `if(dry_run_or_real()){return;}` to just "abort" the execution. You can't really influence the outer layer of a nesting. As such you wouldn't be able to "actually runt he code" in your test function.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```sh
do-stuff() {
  # Pass the name of this function to `dry-run` and do nothing if it
  # returns `true`.
  dry-run ${(%):-%N} && return 1

  echo 'Doing stuff.'
}

dry-run() {
  # If GLOBAL_DRY_RUN has been set, output the contents of the function.
  [[ -v GLOBAL_DRY_RUN ]] && type -f $1

  # The return value of any function is equal to the return value of the 
  # last operation it performed.
}
```

This is how it works in practice:

```sh
% do-stuff
Doing stuff.

% GLOBAL_DRY_RUN='any value'
% do-stuff
do-stuff () {
    dry-run ${(%):-%N} && return 1
    echo 'Doing stuff.'
}

% unset GLOBAL_DRY_RUN
% do-stuff
Doing stuff.
```

It wouldn't *actually* dry-run anything, but it does work in a similar fashion to what you described that you want.